# Как получить доступ к гос. API РФ?

Tags: api

Как я могу получить доступ к API (ГИБДД(проверка штрафов,водителя и ТС), Федеральная налоговая служба (ЕГРЮЛ, ЕГРИП, ИНН), Бюро кредитных историй, Росфинмониторинг, Государственная информационная система о государственных и муниципальных платежах (ГИС ГМП), МВД, ФСИН, Российский Союз Автостраховщиков, Суды общей юрисдикции и Мировые суды и таможенной службы РФ)?

Доступ к ФССП и ФНС можно найти свободно на официальном сайте.

Возможно ли получить доступ ко всем этим ресурсам через систему "СВЭМ"??

Comment: обратитесь в соответствующие инстанции. Но что то мне кажется, что это все Вам абсолютно не нужно

Comment: @KoVadim "Но что то мне кажется, что это все Вам абсолютно не нужно" не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, почему вы так решили?

Comment: я думаю, Вы все прекрасно понимаете.

Comment: @KoVadim к сожалению нет. Можно подробнее услышать?

Comment: Есть требования правил доступа к информации. В рамках действующего законодательства информация в этих ИС защищается в соответствии с законом об информации (149-ФЗ). Это государственные ИС. В логике защиты этих систем не может быть доступа к инф. этих систем неограниченному кругу лиц. В первую очередь есть правила эксплуатации  и прочая техническая документация. Если эти сведения (в том числе по API, процедурам предоставления доступа и пр.) не доступны, значит эта информация тоже охраняется законом. Отсюда, легальный способ получения доступа - обращение к владельцам этих ИС. Пишите запрос.

Comment: собственно я это и хотел сказать, но я не владею в должной мере законодательством этой страны (но мне и не положено по статусу)

Answer (score 0):

Все что вы перечислили просто так не дает доступа. Тот же ФССП который якобы дает, это все бред. Там на ключ у них ограничение в 5 запросов в час, что в итоге не имеет ни какого смысла, мы делали проверку задолженностей, и единственный вариант это разгадка капчи и парсинг сайта. Или же можно распарсить приложение, но нужно будет использовать много прокси и они должны быть из России, иначе они улетают в бан.

Comment: видимо у вас не совсем точная информация, на данный момент "Максимальное число одиночных запросов в час ­— 100. (Ограничение на одиночные запросы считается, как минус час от текущего времени)" - это из официального API https://api-ip.fssp.gov.ru/about